# How to read the XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" 
xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" 
xmlns:db="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/db-routing-1.1.xsd" 
xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.2.xsd" 
xmlns:ds="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/datasource-1.1.xsd"> 

<ds:direct bindOnElement="#document" datasource="DB" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbase" username="root" password="praya123"   autoCommit="false" /> 
<db:executor executeOnElement="Invoice" datasource="DB" executeBefore="true"> 
<db:statement>SELECT * FROM custinfo</db:statement> 
<db:resultSet name="rs_custinfo" /> 
</db:executor> 
<db:executor executeOnElement="Invoice" datasource="DB" executeBefore="true"> 
<db:statement>select * from callRates</db:statement> 
<db:resultSet name="rs_callRates" /> 
</db:executor> 
<db:executor executeOnElement="Invoice" datasource="DB" executeBefore="true"> 
<db:statement>select * from InvoiceSummary</db:statement> 
<db:resultSet name="rs_InvoiceSummary" /> 
</db:executor> 
<db:executor executeOnElement="Invoice" datasource="DB" executeBefore="true"> 
<db:statement>select * from InvoiceDetail</db:statement> 
<db:resultSet name="rs_InvoiceDetail" /> 
</db:executor> 

<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Invoice"> 
<ftl:template> 

<!-- 
<#assign x=1> 
<#list 1..x as i> 

<DETAIL> 
<DT_INV_HDR1>${rs_custinfo[i].BillingAccNo}</DT_INV_HDR1> 
<DT_INV_HDR2>${rs_custinfo[i].CustNo}</DT_INV_HDR2> 
<DT_INV_HDR3>${rs_custinfo[i].InvoiceNo}</DT_INV_HDR3> 
<DT_INV_HDR4>${rs_custinfo[i].InvoiceDate}</DT_INV_HDR4> 
<DT_INV_HDR5>${rs_custinfo[i].PaymentDueDate}</DT_INV_HDR5> 
<DT_INV_HDR6/> 
<DT_INV_HDR7/> 
</DETAIL> 

</#list> 
--> 

</ftl:template> 
</ftl:freemarker> 
</smooks-resource-list>
```

how to fetch data with java ?  Can anyone give any specific way to do that ?

Comment: Learn XML parsing in java. Search for DOM and SAX parser.

Comment: I have tried with both of them. But I failed. Can you tell me any specific function of DOM or SAX, that i can use...?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you got an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for us?

Comment: I used SAX parser. I could parse all informations. But i need to parse only the data

Comment: This is nothing more than a code dump and is no better than your closed question, except for removing the sensative data. Please show us what you've tried, and what's not working. Else hire someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: I could parse all data using SAX parser. but i want only the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DZone has a very good, comprehensive [refacrd](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/using-xml-java) on this you should read.

Comment: Thanks man. Actually the reference book of this document helped me. I used the DOM parser here.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Edit: You'll find a class to parse XML, it may be useful.